# Javascript get an object array filtered only with certain properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects(object is `<Employee>` type) as shown below,

```
[{i: "MCA001", j: 4, n: "KEITH G MCALLISTER", m: null, a: 1, …}
, {...}]
```

i want this  object array filtered with certain properties,
for an instance, filtered array should have few properties,

```
[{i:.., j:.., a:..}]
```

i'm trying to use filter and map functions and still no success.
Appreciate if anyone can help me to figure this out.
Thank you very much.

Comment: so you can loop over and map a new one... `var arr = [{a:1,b:11,c:111},{a:2,b:22,c:222},{a:3,b:33,c:333}]
var updated = arr.map(({ a, b}) => {
  return { a, b }
})
console.log(updated)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You did not read it. :) OP wants to remove properties from object, not reduce the array.

Comment: And @CodeManiac deleted the answer that was correct

Comment: @CodeManiac And I undid the dupe because it was incorrect. It was filtering the array.

Comment: @epascarello and i reverted my deleted answer back too :p

Comment: @epascarello - I read it *too quickly*. There's a difference.

Comment: Good God, though, people. It's not like it's not still a duplicate. Just of a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User:wbamberg/Examples_on_top/Array.prototype.map():v2) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let data = [{i: "MCA001", j: 4, n: "KEITH G MCALLISTER", m: null, a: 1,}, {i: "MCA002", j: 5, n: "KEITH G MCALLISTER", m: null, a: 22,},{i: "MCA0111", j: 5, n: "KEITH G MCALLISTER", m: null, a: 123,}]


let  output = data.map(( {i, j, a} )=> ( {i, j, a} ) )

console.log(output)
```